# Mysql Backup for innoDB

Tags: java, mysql

I am new to mysql backups. I read [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-backup.html) and it is said how to backup a running database,but it is commercial. Please any one tell my how to back up innodb mysql database with its data and how to restore it with clear code samples in a java applications for swing applications
.(how to stop the server,back up, then restart it.. mysql queries and java statements) .

Answer (score 0):

Why does it hava to be Java based? The Mysql command line tools can do what you want which could be scripted.

Also, web tools such as phpMyAdmin allow you to do backups etc

Comment: I am afraid.applications are not always used by developers or those who know other mysql tools.I want to give the database backing up features to the user with some gui s.

Answer (score 0):

You can effectively use the *mysqldump* utility to save backups. It is much more convenient than phpMyAdmin, sepecially in conjunction with a *cron* utility for planning regular backups.

My personal experience teach me always checking what storage engine is used in *mysqldump* backups. Sometimes, it must be manually pointed as MyISAM or InnoDB in a beginning of a dump file.

Please read some useful information about *mysqldump* [here](http://www.handybackup.net/backup_terms/mysqldump.shtml):